# How to fix Undefined offset: 0 in laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am fetching records with pagination. The first page is working fine but when I click on page number 2 then it return following error

```
Undefined offset: 0
```

I am trying following script in controller

```
$Jobs = Jobs::orderBy('job_id', 'asc')->paginate(5);
return view('veteran.job-posting.index',['Jobs'=>$Jobs]);
```

In the blade following code I am trying

```
@if($Jobs)
@foreach($Jobs as $Job)
{{ ucfirst(trans($Job->job_title))  }} 
@endforeach
@endif
```

For pagination I am using following script

```
<div class="pagination-test">
    {{ $Jobs->links() }}
</div>
```

Please guide me why it does returning error when I click on page number 2. I would like to appreciate

**After Request For More Detail from @pseudoanime**

For more detail about error

```
2/2) ErrorException
Undefined offset: 0 (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\project\project-sub-root\resources\views\index.blade.php)
```

Comment: can you post more of your error?

Comment: On which line you are getting this error? Please elaborate more

Comment: Nothing in `storage/logs/laravel.log`? What does your URL look like after clicking on page 2? Does your first page still work when you add `?page=1` to the URL?

Comment: @kerbholz `page=1` is by default page, I don't need to use `?page=1` for first page but for getting more results I have click  on pagination which is landing me on `?page=2`

Comment: Are you sure that error occurs in the template you posted? Because you are viewing `resources/veteran/job-posting/index.blade.php`, but that error is from `resources/views/index.blade.php`.

Comment: @kerbholz I just remove folder for clearance I am aware of this. Thank you

Comment: Can you try replacing `trans()` with `__()`? I noticed that if I use `ucfirst(trans($model->property));` I get an error if `$model->property` is `null` or `""` (empty), but I don't when I use `ucfirst(__($model->property));`. Mind you it's not the same error, but might be what you're experiencing.

Comment: @TimLewis I really appreciate your suggestion. I have tried but unfortunately still facing same error

Comment: No problem; like I said, different error, may or may not have worked. Unfortunately, I don't see anything else in your code that could be throwing that particular error. Try removing/adjusting your code until that error goes away, or double check the stack trace of the error to find the exact line where this issue is being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this outside of the loop

```
{{ $Jobs->links() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to add Pagination like this.

```
@if(count($Jobs) > 0)
   @foreach($Jobs as $Job)
       {{ ucfirst(trans($Job->job_title))  }} 
   @endforeach
   {{ $Jobs->links() }}
@endif
```

With your CSS class

```
@if(count($Jobs) > 0)
   @foreach($Jobs as $Job)
       {{ ucfirst(trans($Job->job_title))  }} 
   @endforeach
   <div class="pagination-test">
        {{ $Jobs->links() }}
   </div>
@endif
```

**Edited Update**

Try With `With` in controller

```
return view('veteran.job-posting.index')->with('Jobs',$Jobs);
```

Comment: @TheCoder try to add @if(count($Jobs) > 0)

Comment: I tried your instruction but still getting same error

Comment: @TheCoder so the error is not for pagination. Something can you check inside the JobsController. Index method/function

Comment: I have also shared the controller script you can look

Comment: @TheCoder can you try this return view('veteran.job-posting.index')->with('Jobs',$Jobs); Check my edited answer.

Comment: what is the result when you execute in the controller inside index method. `return Face::orderBy('created_at','dsc')->paginate(1);` @TheCoder

Comment: @TheCoder and can u check `..?page=1` and `..?page=2` results

Answer (score 1):

Update your controller's function return and use compact function for to pass jobs to view.

```
$jobs = Job::orderBy("id", "asc")->paginate(5);
return view("jobs", compact("jobs"));
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many StackOverflow users are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted, so will not learn from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this for pagination in blade.

```
<ul class="pagination" >
    {!! $Jobs->render() !!}
</ul>
```

Comment: I already did this, actually kindly read the question properly, this is not the question